# Excel Macro Compatibility Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have added my macro to a already existing excel file with macros (build on lower version of excel). It is working fine on my system as well as other systems with same excel version. But when the excel file is opened in other versions, it either crashes or gives error messages like unexpected error occurred(32809)/ compile error. I am using Excel 2010 14.0.7143.500. Can any body tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have a 32-bit version of Excel 2010. Is it possible that you have imported 32-bit functions that need alternative 64-bit versions with compiler directives for 64-bit version of Excel?

Comment: That error number makes me think you're running into the December update bug: http://excelmatters.com/2014/12/10/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/

Comment: I have created my macro on a 32-bit version. I have tested the work book on a 64-bit system with same version of excel that I am having. Its working fine. The error occurs when the macro is running on other subversion of excel like 14.0.7015.1000.

Comment: Again, that implies to me that those systems haven't been patched. A workbook using ActiveX controls on worksheets can't be shared between patched and unpatched machines following that MS update. They are working on a fix, I believe (but I wish they'd hurry up!).

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I had also added a new sheet to the initial excel workbook where I put a button and assigned my macro to it.

Answer (score 1):

The Telemetry Log displays some simple information about the recorded events. Each record displayed in the Telemetry Log contains a title and lists the severity of the event displayed. For errors, the records also include a description of the error together with steps to address the issue. Keep in mind that not all of the records displayed represent errors caused by Office solutions; the Telemetry Log also shows when solutions and files are loaded or closed successfully.
For example, the issue titled "OM Hidden: Comment.Initial Property" appears if a solution or macro-enabled file opened in Word 2013 attempts to get the initials of a commenter who is associated with a comment. Word 2013 features an improved commenting experience that does not display commenter initials by default. The APIs associated with the older commenting model have been hidden in the Word 2013 object model but remain available for backwards-compatibility. The "OM Hidden: Comment.Initial" issue in the indicates the file that attempted to use the API, the application that raised the event (Word 2013), the time and date of the event, and short description about the error and how to fix it.